# undefined index name1 and Undefined index name2

Tags: php, undefined-index

these are the two files in which error is occurred:

html_form.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>Admission Form</h1>
            <br>
            <form action="php_register.php" name="registration">
            Firstname: <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="Enter Firstname"/>
            <br>
            Lastname: <input type="text" name="name2" placeholder="Enter Lastname"/><br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

php_register.php

```
<?php
     $fname=$_POST['name1'];
     $lname=$_POST['name2'];

    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

     if (isset($fname) && isset($lname))
      {
         mysqli_query($conn, "insert into test_table(firstname,lastname) 
         values ('$fname','$lname')");
      }
      else
         echo "<br> Errror....Values are not set in variables...!!!";
?>
```

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name1 in C:\wamp2\www\PHP_project\php_register.php on line 2
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0022  131712  {main}( )   ...\php_register.php:0

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name2 in C:\wamp2\www\PHP_project\php_register.php on line 3
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0022  131712  {main}( )   ...\php_register.php:0

Errror....Values are not set in variables...!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, form method is **GET** but you are trying to get values By `$_POST`.

You didn't define form POST method then you can get values by `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` as:

```
$_GET['name1'];
$_GET['name2'];
```

or

```
$_REQUEST['name1'];
$_REQUEST['name2'];
```

If you want to use `$_POST` then you should define form `method="post"`

If you have no idea about form method, It's a better way to use `$_REQUEST`. By `$_REQUEST` you can get both type values.

Example:

```
$fname=isset($_POST['name1'])?$_POST['name1']:'';
 $lname=isset($_POST['name2'])?$_POST['name2']:'';

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

 if (!empty($fname) && !empty($lname))
  {
     mysqli_query($conn, "insert into test_table(firstname,lastname) 
     values ('$fname','$lname')");
  }
  else
     echo "<br> Errror....Values are not set in variables...!!!";
```

Comment: Now i defined the method in html file as method="post" but still there is same problem...

Comment: check it isset($_REQUEST['name2']). it's good habit to avoid such error.

Comment: yup now its working. I replaced the $_POST method by $_REQUEST and now it is inserting the records.... Thanks alot Gurfan Hasan bhai... I had been suffering by this problem for number of days and you solved it. Thanks again.....

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `method="post"` to your `<form>` tag.

Also you could a check if those values are set before on your `php_register.php` page to ensure the script will run successfully.

e.g.

```
if (empty($_POST['name1']) || empty($POST['name2']) { 
    // some kind of error setting and redirecting back maybe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u don't declare POST or GET in the form ,but u use $_POST['name1'] to get the value, thats where the error occured.

Comment: oh, well then u should var_dump() the data u post ,and find where is wrong, if $_POST['name1'] == {your data}, we can dismiss the problem from the frontend.

Comment: yup now its working. I replaced the $_POST method by $_REQUEST and now it is inserting the records....

Comment: if u r satisfied with my answer.it will be so appreciated to adopt it.